# How do I extract a URL that is itself passed as URL parameter without translating the percent characters?

Tags: php

I'm passing a URL as a URL parameter, like this:

> save_deal.php?url=http://my.angieslist.com/thebigdeal/default.aspx?itemid=%2bTZi%2bk0M5%2b8%3d&user=1965

In `save_deal.php`, I access the `url` parameter quite simply like this:

```
$url = $_GET["url"];
```

But the value of `$url` is then

> http://my.angieslist.com/thebigdeal/default.aspx?itemid= TZi k0M5 8=

That is, the weird %2b and other such percent characters have been converted into something else. How can I get the exact same string instead of this translated version (which has converted the percent characters into something else)?

Comment: The characters are supposed to get converted.  This is like asking why, when fetching the contents of the following XML element, you get `foo<bar` instead of `foo&lt;bar`: `<e>foo&lt;bar</e>`.  `foo<bar` is the value, it's just been escaped for storage/transport.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$_GET will always contain the normalized and splitted values. You might be able to recover the raw parameter from the `QUERY_STRING` with:

```
$url = substr(strstr($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"], "url="), 4);
```

A regex would be more reliable, and this will only work if the ?url= parameter is really present and if no other real parameters follow.

Comment: Really? :-( You're suggesting him to read the raw query string instead of just passing the URL correctly to begin with?

Comment: Yes. Really. I'm not sure you can assume he has control over the incoming links. Despite that there is no dark magic surrounding the QUERY_STRING.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the URL should get encoded again when passed as a query string argument, making the itemid value encoded twice - once as an argument to angieslist, and than again as part of the entire URL (which is itself a query string argument).

To make that clearer, the code that creates the URL should look something like that:

```
<?php
$itemid = '+TZi+k0M5+8=';
$angieslist_url = 'http://my.angieslist.com/thebigdeal/default.aspx?itemid=' . urlencode($itemid);
// First of all, the itemid is encoded when passed as a query string argument, resulting in:
// http://my.angieslist.com/thebigdeal/default.aspx?itemid=%2bTZi%2bk0M5%2b8%3d


$savedeal_url = 'save_deal.php?url=' . urlencode($angieslist_url);    
// Here, the entire URL is used as an query string argument, which means it should be encoded just like any other argument, resulting in:
// save_deal.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmy.angieslist.com%2Fthebigdeal%2Fdefault.aspx%3Fitemid%3D%252BTZi%252Bk0M5%252B8%253D
```

Your HTTP server will take care of decoding query string arguments back to plain text, which means that when you're reading `$_GET['url']` you won't get the fully encoded URL - one "layer" of encoding will be stripped off, resulting in the correct URL - `http://my.angieslist.com/thebigdeal/default.aspx?itemid=%2bTZi%2bk0M5%2b8%3d`.